# Cannot delete document, error: The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user

Tags: document-library, word, delete, lock

I am using SP 2013 on-premise. I have an document library named Documents. I have added a new Word document. I try to remove this document, but it gives me an error:

> Het bestand is momenteel uitgecheckt of vergrendeld om te worden bewerkt door een andere gebruiker

Translated to English:

> The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user

In uls I found these errors:

> 1)
>   =i:0).w|s-1-5-21-2290183699-4262213786-291648712-56877, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://aintranet.myCompany.com/Project
>   ,bstrListName={C0C600AD-327A-4AF1-AA6E-1A280EC93796} ,lID=4
>   ,dwDeleteOp=4 ,bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress=True
>
> 2)  Exception occured in scope
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Recycle.
>   Exception=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Het bestand is momenteel
>   uitgecheckt of vergrendeld om te worden bewerkt door een andere
>   gebruiker. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Het
>   bestand is momenteel uitgecheckt of vergrendeld om te worden bewerkt
>   door een andere
>   gebruiker.0x80070021
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)     -  --
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.DeleteCore(DeleteOp deleteOp)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)
>
> 3) Original error: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Het bestand is
>   momenteel uitgecheckt of vergrendeld om te worden bewerkt door een
>   andere gebruiker. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Het bestand is momenteel uitgecheckt of vergrendeld om te worden
>   bewerkt door een andere
>   gebruiker.0x80070021
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.DeleteItem(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)     -  --
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DeleteItem(String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrListName, Int32 lID, UInt32 dwDeleteOp, Boolean
>   bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Guid& pgDeleteTransactionId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.DeleteCore(DeleteOp deleteOp)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out the document?

Comment: The error is saying some one else has checked out that document. You will have to ask that user to check in/undo check out the document for deleting it

Comment: Or as an admin, override the checkout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine the item using PowerShell you can get a better idea of what is going on. In all the cases where I have seen it the lock expires after short period(20 minutes) and has been caused by word setting a lock when a user has selected to edit the file:

```
$web = Get-SpWeb http://somesite.net
$item = $web.GetListItem("/relative/url/to/item.doc")
$item.file.LockType
$item.file.LockedByUser
$item.file.LockExpires
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are facing this error while deleting empty folder "The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user.", Then it might be because of there are documents in the library that don't have a major version published.

Yo can go into the Library Settings and take ownership of the files. Then delete the entries, and the folder can be deleted.

Library Tools > Library > Library Settings > Permissions and Management > Manage files which have no checked in version

Comment: This is something happening to a SP site I'm managing. Do you know what causes these files to be _locked_ by not visible? What are users doing to these files?

Comment: Files uploaded on SharePoint will be visible to others only when Checked In.   If document has no major version published, then only creator can see them.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect from SharePoint Designer using the farm account. Checkout the document. (The one it already says as checked out). Then checkin back. Now you will be able to delete.

This is an error I have overcome many times.

Comment: For those with 2010 that have ended up here looking for help...  With SharePoint 2010, you can just do an "Undo Check Out" from any user, in SharePoint Designer, that has admin privs.  Then the files can be deleted normally (either from web or from the designer).

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely the document is opened in Microsoft Office Word, therefor locked exclusively by the client.

'Locked' is a different state than 'Checked Out' as highlighted in 'Bunzab' response.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with users, It is very likely the document is opened in Microsoft Office Word by one user with checkout and edit.

They have not properly closed it and checkin.

If you look on file in document library it will have 'Locked' is a different state than 'Checked Out' as highlighted. you need to select it and discard checkout

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  What I eventually discovered was that when I used the "+New" option to create a new Word Document, that it must have been Shared automatically.  I turned off sharing for the file, and I was able to delete it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, click the 3 dots (...) next to the file and choose 'More, Discard Checkout'. Then, you can delete the file.

Note: If someone is working on the file then you might want to try getting them to save their changes, and closing the file first.